# Duplicate value in column error - Azure Analysis Services

Tags: powerbi, azure-analysis-services

I have a table in my model which is extracting data from an adls location in Azure Datalake. 
I am getting the following error while deploying the model:

```
'Column 'xy_id' in Table 'ABC' contains a duplicate value '' and this is not allowed for columns on the one side of a many-to-one relationship or for columns that are used as the primary key of a table.
```

I have checked the adls file for duplicates. There are no duplicate values. Also checked the count and distinct count in AAS which is same.

All the tables are getting processed successfully. The error comes on the "Deploy Metadata" step and the deployment fails.

There are only 3 tables in the model. I have created a One to Many relationship from table ABC to other 2 tables.

Can anyone suggest any fixes? I am not able to figure out why I am facing this error.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You are interacting with different systems which stores data in different ways. By default Azure Analysis Services is case INsensitive.
This means that AAA and aAa are the exact same thing. Therefore, it will cause issues if:

- the field is defined as Unique in AAS
- the field is defined as Primary Key in AAS
- the field is on the one-side of a one-to-many relationship

You can either solve this issue in the data source or change the database settings in SSMS.

However, as a general best-practice please define relationship only on integer fields. For example, you could create a Surrogate Key in the data source.